# JSTL SQL How to display column names as a column in a table?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have seen many examples that displays column names in header row in table, and the data rows as rows in a table.
But I need to display Column name as a first column of a table.
How to do it?
I wish to display a single record selected based on ID. (using JSTL query)

ColumnName     - Value
(e.g.)

`SQL Query : SELECT serial as 'Serial Number', make as 'Sys Make', model as 'Sys Model' from hardware where id = 1;`

- Details for the System ID : 1
- Serial Number : XXXXXXX
- Sys Make : YYYY
- Sys Model : ZZZZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended with my own solution to use JavaSE instead of JSTL

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT serial as 'Serial Number', make as 'Sys Make', model as 'Sys Model' from hardware where ID =" + id;
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
rs.beforeFirst();
while (rs.next()) {
  for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
     out.println("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(i) +"</td></tr>");
                       }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you presumably already know the column names for the SELECT statement, you would put them in as static text values.  I would do something like:
SELECT 'Serial Number: ', serial_number, 'Make: ', make, 'Model: ', model FROM tblTheTable WHERE id = TheID;

Comment: No, It has more than 40 columns, So I iterate it through to display in a table, columnsName as first column of a table, and data as a second column of a table.